# How to update attribute value by using ref in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-ref

In below code there is "opened" attribute and I want to change its value by using ref. Here I am using ref as indexed array.

```
<Menu renderer={renderers.SlideInMenu} ref={(Menu) => { this.rowRefs[item.id] = Menu; }} opened={false}>
```

I tried it as

```
function updateRef(id){
  React.findDOMNode(this.refs.id).setAttribute("opened", true);
}
```

Can anyone please explain how to create an indexed reference and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Props should be immutable and for the purpose of dynamically <strike>change</strike> update them you should consider to set them via state.

Your code should look like:

```
<Menu renderer={renderers.SlideInMenu} ref={component => this.menuRef = component }} opened={this.state.opened}>
```

In which case the `<Menu .. >` is assumed to be rendered in a component which has a state variable `opened` which you can change using `this.setState({opened: true})` . This state change will make your UI rerender hence `<Menu .. >`  will be rendered with `opened={true}`.

Also if you want to use `ref`, then you should consider making a state variable inside `Menu` which should be initialized with `opened` prop, and you should have a method in the `Menu` which will change the state.

Your code should look like below:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           menuOpened: props.opened
       }
    }

    changeMenuOpened = (value) => {
       this.setState({
           menuOpened: value
       })
    }

    .....
}
```

and then you can just call the `changeMenuOpened` method using `Menu`'s ref from the parent.

```
this.menuRef.changeMenuOpened(true);
```

Comment: I don't think ref will work with indexed array. Do you any example for this ?

Comment: create an array in the constructor say `this.itemRefs = []` and push the refs inside it, and when using, fetch it from the array and use it like this `this.itemRefs[x].something()`. There is no restriction in using refs like that as bottom of line is all are JS objects. :)